# Область видимости исключения в блоке catch

Tags: javascript, переменные, scope, javascript-faq

Собственно, почему не функция, а только сам блок?

Проверено в Хроме, FF, IE11 и Опере 12.

```js
function test() {
  var e = 10, x = 5;

  try {
    console.log(e, x); // 10 5
    throw 15;
  } catch (e) {
    var x;
    console.log(e, x); // 15 5
    e = x = 17;
    console.log(e, x); // 17 17
  } finally {
    console.log(e, x); // 10 17
  }
}

test();
```

Ну и ES6-версия с декомпозицией:

```js
function test() {
  var e = 10, x = 5;

  try {
    console.log(e, x); // 10 5
    throw {e: 15, x:3};
  } catch ({e, x}) {
    console.log(e, x); // 15 3
    e = x = 17;
    console.log(e, x); // 17 17
  } finally {
    console.log(e, x); // 10 5
  }
}

test();
```

Comment: JavaScript создает идентификатор **e** при входе в блок **catch** и уничтожает при выходе. Он перекрывает локальную переменную **e**. Такова особенность языка.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, а в стандарте это где-то написано?

Comment: http://es5.github.io/#x12.14   3. Let catchEnv be the result of calling NewDeclarativeEnvironment passing oldEnv as the argument.  4. Call the CreateMutableBinding concrete method of catchEnv passing the Identifier String value as the argument.  5. Call the SetMutableBinding concrete method of catchEnv passing the Identifier, C and false as arguments. Note that the last argument is immaterial in this situation.  6. Set the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment to catchEnv.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, а разве NewDeclarativeEnvironment не означает собственный скоуп? Но у catch'а ведь его нет? Или это такая магия за счёт всплытия объявлений, что всплывает всё кроме исключения? Как-то странно получается...

Comment: @Qwertiy, старый вопросец на EN: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926237/javascript-catch-clause-scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Обратимся к спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-catchclauseevaluation):

> *Catch* : **catch** ( *CatchParameter* ) *Block*
>
> 1. в *oldEnv* сохраняется *LexicalEnvironment* из текущего контекста
> 2. создается *catchEnv* как *NewDeclarativeEnvironment(oldEnv)*.
> 3. для каждого имени аргумента из *BoundNames* в *CatchParameter* в *catchEnv* создается *MutableBinding*
> 4. текущим *LexicalEnvironment* в контексте устанавливается *catchEnv*
> 5. в *status* сохраняется результат *BindingInitialization*
> 6. если *status* не нормальный
>
>    1. текущим *LexicalEnvironment* в контексте устанавливается *oldEnv*
>    2. значением *catch* блока устанавливается значение *status*
> 7. В *B* сохраняется результат выполнения *Block.*
> 8. текущим *LexicalEnvironment* в контексте устанавливается *oldEnv*
> 9. значением *catch* блока устанавливается значение *B*

**Что можно отметить в данном алгоритме?**

1. при входе в *catch* создается новый *LexicalEnvironment*
2. значения указанные в параметрах *catch* связываются с новым *LexicalEnvironment*
3. при выходе - **всегда** восстанавливается старый *LexicalEnvironment*

Таким образом `e` объявленную выше `var e=10` перекрывает `e` в выражении `catch (e)`, значение которой и используется внутри блока.

И так как при выходе из блока восстанавливается старый *LexicalEnvironment*, внутри блока *finally* будет видна переменная объявленная через *var*.

Теперь можно перейти к вопросу из комментария:

> @VladimirGamalian, а разве NewDeclarativeEnvironment не означает собственный скоуп? Но у catch'а ведь его нет? Или это такая магия за счёт всплытия объявлений, что всплывает всё кроме исключения? Как-то странно получается...

В контексте выполнения присутствуют [два дополнительных свойства](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-23)

- *LexicalEnvironment* - определяет [Lexical Environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-lexical-environments), в котором хранятся идентификаторы созданные в коде в текущем контексте
- *VariableEnvironment* - определяет [Lexical Environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-lexical-environments), в котором *EnvironmentRecord* хранит привязки созданные с помощью *VariableStatements* в текущем контексте

При использовании [выражения `var`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-variable-statement) переменные добавляются в *VariableEnvironment* текущего контекста. Так как при заходе в `catch` меняется только *LexicalEnvironment* - то становится не важно в каком месте переменная объявлена с помощью `var` - она все равно будет добавлена в *VariableEnvironment* и будет доступна из любого места в текущем контексте выполнения.

Comment: Там дело не во всплытии. Переменные, созданные при помощи eval не всплывают, но такая переменная из блока catch всё равно видна в функции далее. Значит привязка идёт именно к скоупу функции и только исключение привязано к какому-то особому блоку. Надо этот момент как-то прояснить и дополнить.

Comment: @Qwertiy, _Переменные, созданные при помощи eval не всплывают_ - добавь код не совсем понял

Comment: `var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4; (function () { console.log(a, b, c, d); var a = 11; eval('var b = 12'); console.log(a, b, c, d); try { throw 0 } catch (e) { var c = 13; eval('var d = 14'); console.log(a, b, c, d); } console.log(a, b, c, d); })();` Сначала видим 2 и 4 из верхней области, 1 и 3 перекрыты объявленными var'ами. Потом в рантайме создаётся переменная b = 12 и она перекрывает внешнюю. А затем, в блоке catch таким же образом создаётся c = 14. Она видна вне блока catch, что означает, что даже в рантайме привязка идёт к скоупу функции, а не тому скоупу, к которому привязано исключение.

Comment: Даже так - тут видно, что глобальное значение не попортилось: `var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4; (function () { console.log(a, b, c, d); var a = 11; eval('var b = 12'); console.log(a, b, c, d); try { throw 0 } catch (e) { var c = 13; eval('var d = 14'); console.log(a, b, c, d); } console.log(a, b, c, d); a = 21, b = 22, c = 23, d = 24; console.log(a, b, c, d); })(); console.log(a, b, c, d);`

Comment: @Qwertiy :-) я не понял, что именно в этом коде противоречит ответу :-) но вся суть в том _как_ объявлены переменные. Когда переменная объявляется через `var` - она находится в _VariableEnvironment_, который как раз создается довольно редко: при входе в тег _script_, в модуле, в функции. А в _catch_ создается _LexicalEnvironment_ - это, то же самое, но немного другое :-) и создается уже на уровне блока, поэтому после добавления даже с помощью eval переменной в _VariableEnvironment_ она становится видна везде где виден этот _Environment_

Comment: Вот что-то такое добавь во вторую часть ответа. И про связь и разницу между NewDeclarativeEnvironment, VariableEnvironment, LexicalEnvironment.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага,  я сначала хотел, а потом подумал, что много получится и хватит того что сейчас написано :-)

Comment: @Qwertiy, обновил ответ, посмотри :)

Comment: Ага, держи галочку :)

Answer (score -1):

В блоке catch создается копия объекта созданного оператором throw, finally же имеет доступ к внешнему по отношению к catch объекту, который не менялся.

**Обновление**

В catch передается временных безымянный объект созданный throw, поля которого переезжают в глобальный объект и перекрывают переменные e и x, по выходу из catch он уничтожается, поэтому в finally выводится объявленные в начале функции e и x.

Comment: Копия объекта? о_О Ты язык не перепутал? К внешнему объекту? Тут же вообще о переменных речь...

Comment: Да, да. Но ямел ввиду, что имена в блоке catch перекрывают собой внешнюю облать видимости. Можно было и понять... Объекту? А что по Вашему не объект в JS?

Comment: У него нет своей области видимости ни для чего, кроме исключения.

Comment: @Qwertiy, глянь ссылку, там они говорят что `catch` по аналогии с `with`

Comment: <pre><code>throw {e: 15, x:3};</code></pre> Так об этом и речь...

Comment: @Grundy, интересно. А не хочешь из этого ответ собрать?