# Почему браузер дважды обращается к Symbol.unscopables?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
with(new Proxy({}, {
  has() { return true },
  get(obj, key, proxy) { return console.log(String(key)) } })
) {
  a--
}
```

Вывод в Chrome:

```
Symbol(Symbol.unscopables)
a
Symbol(Symbol.unscopables)
```

Вывод в Firefox:

```
Symbol(Symbol.unscopables)
Symbol(Symbol.unscopables)
a
```

Насколько я понимаю, одно обращение связано с чтением, а другое с записью.

<s>Логично, что конструкция `a--` должна записать значение в то же место, откуда прочитала.</s> Нет, это не так.

А двойное чтение из `Symbol.unscopables` как бы намекает, что это не так и у меня есть возможность отдать нечто для чтения, но сказать, что в мой объект этого записывать не надо?

Неужели это так и задумано? Что на эту тему говорит стандарт?

Собственно, в Хроме и FF такое почти прокатывает - чтение и запись связаны с разными объектами, однако работает по-разному:

Update: Safari 10 читает `Symbol.unscopables` только один раз.

```js
var a, b, flag = true

with (a = { x: 7 })
  with (b = { x: 4, get [Symbol.unscopables]() { return { x: flag=!flag } } })
    x++

                 // Chrome   FF       Safari   Edge
console.log(a)   // {x:5}    {x:7}    {x:7}    {x:5}
console.log(b)   // {x:4}    {x:8}    {x:5}    {x:4}
```

PS: [Этот вопрос по-английски.](//stackoverflow.com/q/40595389/4928642)

Comment: это все из-за Proxy :)

Comment: За `with` Вам ночью оборотень голову отъест :)

Comment: суть в двух словах: в это свойство помещаются значения которые не в скопе with объявлены, поэтому этот вызов будет для каждой промежуточной переменной

Comment: @Grundy, во втором примере я меняю только `x` и это работает. Что и странно. Да ещё и работает по разному, что ещё более странно. Вопрос, почему :) И да, а где тут промежуточная переменная?

Comment: @Other, а разработчиков lodash ещё не съел? `_.template("<div></div>")` превращается в `function (obj){obj||(obj={});var __t,__p='';with(obj){__p+='<div></div>';}return __p}`

Comment: @Qwertiy, а что твой последний пример должен показывать?

Comment: @Grundy, прочитали из одного объекта, а записали - в другой. Это весьма неожиданно для инкремента - разве нет?

Comment: неа, это вот примерно так и работает :) когда первый раз взял значение - проверил что оно в скопе, второй раз при присвоении - проверяет и так как флаг поменялся - пишет его не в текущий скоп

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48502/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-grundy).

Comment: Сомнительная возможность, но, как и `eval`, иногда приходится к месту. `Lodash` используют к месту.

Comment: @Other, на самом деле, там не всегда with. Если передать имя переменной в опции, то with не будет. Но по умолчанию он там вполне себе на месте.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40595389/4928642

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно спецификации, @@unscopables в этом случае должно читаться только один раз.  Детали (к сожаления по английски) в https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2017-February/047725.html

Следовательно Chrome и Firefox не следуют спецификации, а Safari следует.

Смотрите также https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1341061 и https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5992

Answer (score 2):

Обратимся к [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-well-known-symbols), в таблице 1 находится описание символа `@@unscopables`

> An object valued property whose own property names are property names that are excluded from the with environment bindings of the associated object.

> Объект, в котором названия свойств совпадают со свойствами исключенными из *with* связывания.

Значение этого свойства проверяется в функции [HasBindings(N)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-environment-records-hasbinding-n)

1. Let envRec be the object Environment Record for which the method was invoked.
2. Let bindings be the binding object for envRec.
3. Let foundBinding be HasProperty(bindings, N)
4. ReturnIfAbrupt(foundBinding).
5. If foundBinding is false, return false.
6. If the withEnvironment flag of envRec is false, return true.
7. Let unscopables be Get(bindings, @@unscopables).
8. ReturnIfAbrupt(unscopables).
9. If Type(unscopables) is Object, then

   1. Let blocked be ToBoolean(Get(unscopables, N)).
   2. ReturnIfAbrupt(blocked).
10. If blocked is true, return false.
11. Return true.

Здесь нас интересуют пункты начиная с 6. Если проверяемое свойство `N` находится в блоке `with`, оно всегда проверяется в объекте *unscopables*.

Теперь перейдем к [постфиксному декременту](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-postfix-decrement-operator). В алгоритме есть два ключевых момента:

1. вызов [GetValue(lhs)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-getvalue) - для получения текущего значения
2. вызов [PutValue(lhs, newValue)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-putvalue) - для установки нового значения

Каждая из этих функций в итоге вызывает описанную выше HasBinding.

В обновленном пример добавлена функция `set` и в логах видно, что второй раз вызывается как раз перед ней.

```js
var value = 10;
with(new Proxy({}, {
  has(o, k) {
      console.log('has', String(k));
      return true; // k !== 'console';
    },
    get(obj, key, proxy) {
      console.log('get', String(key));

      if (key === Symbol.unscopables) {
        return {
          a: false,
          console: true
        }
      }

      return value;
    },
    set(o, k, v, proxy) {
      console.log('set', k, v);
      if (k == 'a') value = v;
    }
})) {
  a--;
}
```

Что характерно `firefox` сначала получает все связанные поля, и лишь затем получает значения свойств.

---

Далее можно разобрать второй пример:

```js
var a, b, flag = true
var valueA = 7,
  valueB = 4;
with(a = {
  get x() {
    console.log('get A', flag);
    return valueA;
  }, set x(v) {
    console.log('set A', flag);
    valueA = v;
  }
})
with(b = {
  get x() {
      console.log('get B', flag);
      return valueB;
    }, set x(v) {
      console.log('set B', flag);
      valueB = v;
    },
    get [Symbol.unscopables]() {
      var t = {
        x: flag = !flag
      };
      console.log('Symbol.unscopables', t);

      return t;
    }
})
x++

// Chrome   FF
console.log(valueA) // {x:5}    {x:7}
console.log(valueB) // {x:4}    {x:8}
```

Что тут происходит?

1. постфиксная операция, которая внутри себя вызывает Put и Get
2. getter Symbol.unscopables - который определяет находится ли свойство `x` в текущем `with` или нет. Значение флага меняется на противоположное.

Как можно заметить по логам, сначала значения флага возвращается `false`, что в соответствии со спецификацией указывает на то, что данное имя находится в текущем скопе. Поэтому значение берется из объекта `b`.

Далее флаг выставляется в `true` и при вычслении в каком скопе находится `x` в котороый надо положить, получаем, что он находится не текущем скопе, поэтому значение сохраняется в объекте `a`.

Как видно - Chrome работает в соответствии со спецификацией.

Что касается firefox. <strike>Как можно заметить, firefox не инвертирует значение возвращенное в объекте unscopables, как это указано в спецификации, поэтому значение сначала берется из внешнего `with` и присваивается значению из внутреннего</strike>.

По результатам проверок, можно сделать вывод, что firefox сначала получает свойство **куда** записывать, и лишь затем свойство **откуда** брать значение. Из-за этого в примере, когда значение flag меняется на каждый вызов, происходит расхождение с работой Chrome и EDGE.

Comment: Интересно, что думают об этой штуке любители надёжных и очевидных языков, в которых ногу просто так не отстрелишь? :) А ответ хорош, вот так и нужно обучатся. Жаль только рейтинг у таких ответов куда ниже (я и, наверное, ТС), чем у чего-то, типа "Как в жуквери установить значение у input?".

Comment: @Other, обновил чуть ответ. В ответе про catch было трое :)

Comment: Какой это ответ?

Comment: @Other, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/510270/178988

Comment: Думаю стоит перевести этот ответ на большом SO, там хорошего ответа нет. Впрочем, любого нет.

Comment: @Grundy, на enSO с этим [не согласны](//stackoverflow.com/a/42349142/4928642). А ещё, Сафари читает свойство только 1 раз - я проверил.

Comment: @Qwertiy, что-то я, честно говоря, не совсем уловил суть его рассуждений, может его сюда позвать, может это он ошибается? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, не знаю, кто ошибается, но прикольно, когда последние 3 более-менее разные браузера реализовали свежий стандарт тремя разными способами. Хорошая фича :D

Comment: @Qwertiy, тут самое время было бы высказаться разработчикам стандарта :-) как именно они видел эту фичу :-D

Comment: @Grundy, как костыль - очевидно же ;)

Comment: GetValue и PutValue не вызывают HasBinding в этом случае.  В этом случае, _base_ -- это Environment Record.  Поэтому они вызавают соответственно http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-environment-records-getbindingvalue-n-s и http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-environment-records-setmutablebinding-n-v-s и в обоих случаях не обращаются к HasBinding.  Следовательно и Chrome и Firefox ведут себя неправильно.  Safari следует спецификации.

Comment: @user8680, а почему там base - это Environment Record, а не объект или примитив? Я не совсем понимаю как должен base определяться, и не особо нашел как он и где заполняется, можешь показать место в спецификации?

Comment: `base` был бы объектом в случае `someObj.x++`, но у нас `x++`.  Для того, чтобы понять, что такое `x` начинаем в https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-identifiers-runtime-semantics-evaluation и потом попадаем в https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-resolvebinding, https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-getidentifierreference и оно возвращает Reference к Environment Record который создал `with`.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky, мда, забавно, спасибо! :) Интересно, почему хром и ff и EDGE по другому реализовали